# Deleting Multiple Rows with Zend DB Table Problem

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have this data in my db

```
Col1    Col2
DA      Data1
DA      Data2 
DA      Data3 
DA      Data4
DA      Data5
```

I would like to delete all the values WHERE col1 = DA using my Zend DB Table adapter.
The code below does not seem to work for multiple rows

```
public function delete($key)
    {
        $this->delete('Col1 = "'.$key.'"');
    }
```

How can I adjust it so that I can delete multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway; then the deleting multiple rows is working fine with these below code.

```
   public function delete($key)
   {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(array('Col1' => $key"));
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursive function?
Rename public function delete($key)
to 
public function deleteKey($key)

Comment: Please post some code.Not used recursive functions before.If I rename to public function deletekey($key) what follows?

Comment: it should work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Fundamentals-of-Recursion-in-PHP/1/